# Compute Homology Groups Using Mayer-Vietoris Sequences

Tags: algebraic-topology, homology-cohomology

Exercise 10 of Hatcher is written : - Let $X$ be the quotient space of $S^2$ under the identifications $x \sim -x$ for $x$ in the equator $S^1$. Compute the homology groups $H_i(X)$.

I've done this using cellular homology, yielding the homology groups $$H_i(X) = \begin{cases}
\mathbb{Z}_2, & n=1, \\
\mathbb{Z}, & n=2, \\
0, & \text{otherwise}.
\end{cases}$$

I want to be able to do this using the Mayer-Vietoris sequence however.

If we let $X = S^2/\sim, A = \text{northern hemisphere}, B = \text{southern hemisphere}$, such that $A \cap B = S^1$, then note that $H_n(A) \cong H_n(B) = 0$ since $A$ and $B$ are contractible.

We therefore obtain the following exact sequence $$0 \longrightarrow H_2(S^2/\sim) \longrightarrow \mathbb{Z} \longrightarrow 0 \longrightarrow H_1(X) \longrightarrow 0.$$

I don't think this is correct given that it doesn't yield the same homology groups.

Comment: You probably want $A$ and $B$ to be the *images* of the hemispheres in $X$, not the hemispheres themselves —if they are not contained in $X$ you are not ging to be able to use M–V at all…

Comment: Of course, that should make wonder if $A$ and $B$ are really contractible!

Comment: Yes, finally. Use the reduced M-V to conclude $H_1=Z_2$.